# Many cases in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a form with some fields:

```
name
email
min_age
max_age
city
country
```

**Case 1:** 
 All fields are not necessary, so when the user submit the form, he should get all results from the table.

I could verify if the fields are empty so I create a select query without WHERE clause.

**Case 2:** 
In the second case, the user can set some fields and can leave some empty.

I'm wondering if I should use `OR` or `AND` or Both? 
Because I have many cases ..

**Simple Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE % $name %
OR email LIKE % $email %
OR (age BETWEEN $min_age AND $max_age)
OR city LIKE % $city %
OR country LIKE % $country %
ORDER BY . . .
```

Comment: you can give the user the option to choose or/and , the default i think need to be 'or' , to get more results

Comment: typical of bad design, the above query is not make use of mysql index

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create the query depending on what the user submits through the form?
What's the underlying language?

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE";
if(isset($name)) $qry .= " name LIKE % $name % ";
...
```